# How to test In-app purchase in Sandbox mode iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, skproduct

Am new to In-app purchase integration in iOS application. I have done the coding in the project level and I have **created a Sandbox user in iTunes Connect**. I read many tutorials and Apple Document to test the In-App purchase in DEV mode.
As per the document I have **removed the APPLE ID from iPad Settings** and launched the app from Xcode. But, I **didn't received the Account Alert** from the app. Also, my products are returning **empty in SKProductRequest delegate method didReceiveResponse**. I have posted my code for your reference. Can you please help me on this? Am working since last two days. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
- (void) getAvailProducts
{
    NSLog(@"Fetching Available Products");
    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"com.test.testios.monthly", @"com.test.testios.yearly" ,nil];

    self.productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];

    self.productsRequest.delegate = self;

    [self.productsRequest start];
}

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    //SKProduct *validProduct = nil;

    DebugLog(@"\n Products: %@", response.products);

    NSUInteger count = [response.products count];

    NSLog(@"Request Count: %lu", (unsigned long)count);

    if (count > 0)
    {
        self.validatedProducts = response.products;
        DebugLog(@“\n Products: %@", response.products);

        self.validationCheck = TRUE;

        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];

        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

        // Check subscription        
    }
    else            
    {
      // No products found….              
    }
}
```

Also, I tried with `"monthly and yearly"` instead of `"com.test.testios.monthly and com.test.testios.yearly"`. But, no results.

Edit: Am getting the mentioned ProductIds are invalid in the following code,

```
for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }
```

Comment: First, you have to deal with _"my products are returning empty in SKProductRequest delegate method didReceiveResponse"_. Without SKProduct objects you could not purchase anything. Do you use explicit bundle ID for your app? Is In-App Purchase is allowed in your iPad's  Restrictions settings?

Comment: @EugeneDubinin Thanks for your response. Am using Explicit Bundle ID for this app and also In-App purchase is on in Restrictions Settings. Can you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: `SKProductsRequest` also has these delegates: `request:didFailWithError:` and `requestDidFinish:`. Implement them and debug/log what is returned to there.

Comment: @EugeneDubinin Thank you for your help. Issue fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all.

Fixed the issue and tested the In-App purchase in Sandbox environment. Following items fixed my issue,

```
1. iTunes Agreement was not accepted.
2. Tax and Payment details was not added.
3. Added correct Product Identifier in project.
```